# Does the access speed depend on the number of files on a network share?

Tags: performance, network-shares

In our office we use a RAID5 of SSDs as a network share. This share is accessed as a network drive from Windows-PCs and Mac.
Sometimes this network share becomes awfully slow in terms of access times and transfer speed.

I am not the admin and therefore do not have full insight into the system.

One of the admins now proposed that this may have to do with the number of files that are stored on the network share. Some folders contain millions of few kB files.

Does the access speed depend on the number of files on a network share?